# Where do mysqldump files end up?

Tags: mysql

I just made a backup, but cannot find where it ended up, and find isn't turning up a hit.

The command I used was

```
mysqldump -u root -p myDbName > myDBFile.sql
```

The backup took about 20 mins, and then console returned to

```
root@server [~]#
```

So if I look at root via ftp, where would that file have ended up?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: In your current (in the moment you were running `mysqldump` command) directory

Comment: Thanks Drecker. So in the above case, that would be root, right?

Comment: Shaun - more like root home directory (if `[~]#` means that and I guess it does)

Comment: Cheers Drecker. I still couldn't find it, so ended up specifying a specific folder when doing the dump: /home/mysitename/myDBFile.sql and it worked.

Comment: Shaun: well, `mysqldump` dumps a DB at standard output that's usually undesired behavior, so one uses `>` operator that redirects output somewhere else (usually into file) and the name of the file (if not stated otherwise by starting `/` or `~`) "starts" in current directory and since you haven't specified your dir. it *has to* be in your current dir. The `~` suggests you run command in your home dir. but I'm not sure whether home of root, or home of any other user. Next time you may just run `mysqldump` cmd. and immediately ofter that `ls` cmd. you'll see the file is in that directory.